# Consumir webservices desde asp.net

Tags: asp.net, webservice

Tengo una aplicación asp.net C# (VS 2010), donde tengo un formulario con un *textbox*, un botón (para buscar registros según ID, y debo pasárselo como string al *web service*) y un **gridview**,

Pero los datos los tengo que sacar de un *web service* REST hecho en **node.js** que está en otro servidor dentro de la red.

Soy nuevo en *web services* así que no sé cómo hacer esto.

Ayuda por favor, ¿sugerencias?

Comment: Tip: Si un webservice esta hecho con una u otra tecnologia, no afecta en la implementación del cliente, la idea del web service es quitar dependiencia, solo debes de investigar si acepta json o xml (que es lo mas comun) y sobre eso realizar tu implementación de tu cliente

Comment: si acepta json, pero hasta ahora no he podido agregar la referencia al ws, no encuentra nada en la url que esta alojado

Comment: Saludos mulder, bienvenido/a a SOes, te sugiero darte una vuelta por https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour para que veas el funcionamiento adecuado del sitio y de paso obtienes tu primera medalla :D

Answer (score 1):

Suponiendo que el servicio retorna **JSON**, debemos seguir los pasos:

1. Cree el URI de solicitud RestfUL.
2. Publique URI y obtenga la respuesta de `HttpWebResponse`.
3. Convierte ResponseStreem en objeto serializado de la función `DataContractJsonSerialized`.
4. Obtenga los resultados / elementos particulares del objeto serializado.

Ese es el codigo en **C#** algo generico

```
    public static object MakeRequest(string requestUrl, object JSONRequest, string JSONmethod, string JSONContentType, Type JSONResponseType) {  

    try {  
        HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(requestUrl) as HttpWebRequest;  
        //WebRequest WR = WebRequest.Create(requestUrl);   
        string sb = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(JSONRequest);  
        request.Method = JSONmethod;  
        // "POST";request.ContentType = JSONContentType; // "application/json";   
        Byte[] bt = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sb);  
        Stream st = request.GetRequestStream();  
        st.Write(bt, 0, bt.Length);  
        st.Close();  


        using(HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse) {  

            if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK) throw new Exception(String.Format(  
                "Server error (HTTP {0}: {1}).", response.StatusCode,  
            response.StatusDescription));  

            // DataContractJsonSerializer jsonSerializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Response));// object objResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject();Stream stream1 = response.GetResponseStream();   
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream1);  
            string strsb = sr.ReadToEnd();  
            object objResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(strsb, JSONResponseType);  

            return objResponse;  
        }  
    } catch (Exception e) {  

        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);  
        return null;  
    }  
}
```